# Screen resolution got zoomed after installing nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, display-resolution

After installing nvidia driver my screen got zoomed. I cant fix it resolution. Is there any way to solve this p roblem ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar or maybe the same problem in Ubuntu Mate 16.04. It appeared that the Nvidia driver I installed for my Quadro card changed the dpi settings of my laptop screen from 96*96 to 140*140. The 140*140 DPI setting made everything look slightly zoomed/too big and blurry.

What worked for me was adding the DPI setting to the `xorg.conf` file:

1. Open the `etc/x11/xorg.conf` file with `nano` by typing this in your console:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
   ```

   It's a good idea to make a backup of this file first before changing anything.
2. Look for the line that says: `Section "Monitor"`.
3. Add the following rule into that section: `Option "DPI"   "96 x 96"` so that it looks a bit like this example:

   ```
   Section "Monitor"
       Identifier     "Monitor0"
       Option "DPI"   "96 x 96"
   EndSection
   ```

   You can change the DPI value if you need a different DPI setting instead.
4. Save <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and close <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> the `xorg.conf` file in nano.
5. Reboot Ubuntu

Your monitor should now use the proper DPI setting and your desktop should look sharp and normal again.

Reference used: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1612068

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this in `nvidia-settings`, open it and choose `X server display configuration` on the left.

Now at the bottom is a slider named `underscan` adjusting this will move the boarders of your screen

> [image]

You can also open the `advanced` section and manually enter the values

> [image]